# When rebuilding sql server on a new machine, should SMK be restored prior to or after restoring system dbs?

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2019, encryption, service-master-key

Service Master key is at top of sql server encryption hierarchy. Linked server, credentials, database master key (if any) are encrypted using the service master key.

When rebuilding a sql server using a fresh installation, usually the process is to restore the system dbs, followed by user dbs.

But SMK can only be decrypted by the new machine if the new machine uses the same sql server service domain credentials. This is because the SMK can only be decrypted/opened by same Computer name principal or domain service account.

So without restoring the SMK, the encrypted elements (example: linked server) will fail to work if the new machine doesn't use the same sql server service account.

This question is assuming I have the backup of the source server's SMK. And assuming the target computer has a new name (no access to previous sql server computer principal) and we don't have any record of the source sql server service's domain service account. So assume the target sql server will use a new service account (same domain).

Restoring the SMK does the following:

> When the service master key is restored, SQL Server decrypts all the
> keys and secrets that have been encrypted with the current service
> master key, and then encrypts them with the service master key loaded
> from the backup file.

So if I restore the system dbs and then restore SMK, it will try to decrypt everything with source server's SMK (since we have restored master db), there by messing up the elements that were previously encrypted by the original server's SMK (because new sql svc account won't be able to decrypt), and then it will try to encrypt everything with the original server's SMK.

Effectively the encryption will be messed up. Have I understood this right?

Comment: `master` contains the SMK, so when you restore `master` it will decrypt using the old SMK and re-encrypt everything using a new one. Also [the docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/restore-the-service-master-key?view=sql-server-ver16) "Warning: It is unlikely that you will ever need to restore the service master key. If you do, you should proceed with extreme caution. For more information, see Back Up the Service Master Key."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I backup and restore the SMK when performing a server upgrade and migration?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/313029/should-i-backup-and-restore-the-smk-when-performing-a-server-upgrade-and-migrati) You asked this question before

Comment: When I restore master it won't be able to decrypt the SMK unless the pcname principal or service account is the same. So this question is assuming target is a new computer and different servcie account.

Comment: This is why it's so important to make a backup of the Service Master Key.  If you have a backup, you can restore that backup without issue, and voila, your server can open TDE encrypted databases that use that SMK.

Comment: `When the service master key is restored, SQL Server decrypts all the keys and secrets that have been encrypted with the current service master key, and then encrypts them with the service master key loaded from the backup file.`